# how to get the zip file and unzip using restapi and Ionic.Zip

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, qualtrics

I need to grab the zip file from Qualtric using rest API in .net. I do not know how to correctly put the zip file from IRestResponse into the ZipInputStream. I'm currently calling the content from the response(when I debug it, looks like the zip file is there). but it throws me an error saying 'Illegal characters in path.' This makes me wonder if I need to unwrap some shields from the content and then may display the right zip file...I see some example in java can use

```
response.getEntity().getContent()
```

But I can not get it right in C#

```
var client1 = new RestClient(fileUrl);
var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request1.AddHeader("postman-token", "xxxx");
request1.AddHeader("X-API-TOKEN", "xxxx");
request1.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request1.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"format\" : \"csv\",\n\t\"surveyId\" : \"xxxx\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse responsedata = client1.Execute(request1);
ZipInputStream zs = new ZipInputStream(responsedata.Content);
using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zs))
{
    foreach (ZipEntry e in zip1)
    {
        e.Extract("Y:/", ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming Windows: Perhaps you meant `Y:\ ` ? `Y:/` would be an illegal path.

Comment: Was given an error in this line zipInputStream zs = new ZipInputStream(responsedata.Content);   The error comes from the Content